# Grunt will simply not install on my Win 8.1 machine

Tags: gruntjs

I made a folder g in root(C:/) in where I try to install Grunt via npm.
I sucessfull made: npm install -g grunt-cli.
I configured package.json to this:

```
{
    "name": "testing",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5" },
    "description": "testing",
    "main": "index.html",
    "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5"
  }
}
```

So good so far.
BUT: When I try to install Grunt: npm install grunt --save-dev and modules(plugins) then I run into this error: npm WARN package.json testing@0.0.0 No repository field...

I use GitHub where I've forked Grunt and Grunticon.

Then I can't succed with nothing towards installing Grunt...

Any good clues and help in solving this?

Comment: Warnings are just that: warnings. They are not errors. Either things should be working, or you probably received a different error. We'll need more information to help. Can you update the question with the output from your console when you run `npm install grunt --save-dev` ?

Comment: npm WARN package.json testing@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json testing@0.0.0 No README data
grunt@0.4.5 node_modules\grunt

Comment: ├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
├── which@1.0.8
├── eventemitter2@0.4.14
├── getobject@0.1.0
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── colors@0.6.2
├── async@0.1.22
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0
├── exit@0.1.2
├── lodash@0.9.2
├── coffee-script@1.3.3
├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
├── underscore.string@2.2.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.5.0)
├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.0, graceful-fs@1.2.3)
├── js-yaml@2.0.5 (esprima@1.0.4, argparse@0.1.16)
├── grunt-legacy-log@0.1.1 (underscore.string@2.3.3, lodash@2
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.1, glob@3.2.11)

Comment: Hey @tomwell, this is really difficult to read, can you edit the question and add it there (and then delete those comments)? I'll see if I can recreate the issue some time today, but I'm not sure exactly what's going on right now.

Comment: In my Win 8.1 computer i made a g-folder in Root (C:\).

Comment: In which i created these folders: Grunt, grunticon, node_Modules and configured package.json file.

Comment: When i run: npm install -g grunt then it outputs these lines in my Console ( WindowsShell ):

Comment: npm WARN package.json testing@0.0.0 No repository field. npm WARN package.json testing@0.0.0 No README data grunt@0.4.5 node_modules\grunt

Comment: ...and all the lines succeded just stated like above...

Comment: I hope it makes sense now jakerella. I'm realy not an expert regarding grunt and Node, JavaScript but would so much like to progress - and therefor simply need to have a local insta. of grunt :-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I see the problem clearly now. Here are some instructions for getting Grunt running, try to follow these exactly, do not create any other folders as it could cause issues for Grunt or Node.

1. Create a folder for your project, this can be anywhere on your system.
2. Save the file you have above as `package.json` in that folder.
3. Now install the global Grunt CLI
   `~$ npm install -g grunt-cli`  <-- Note this is "grunt-cli" NOT "grunt"
4. Then go to the new directory you created and run this command:
   `~/new-directoty$ npm install`
   This will install the Grunt runtime locally for your project because it is specified in `package.json`
5. Create a very simple config file in the new directory and name it `Gruntfile.js`:

   `module.exports = function(grunt) {
     grunt.initConfig({ /* your config will go in here */ });
     /* multi-task definitions go here */
   };`
6. Now try to run Grunt just to test that it works:
   `~/new-directory$ grunt`

After that you are ready to start adding plugins, but that's a bigger topic. Good luck.

Comment: Hello again! Thanks for the reply. When i follow your advices abowe with the very simple Gruntfile.js: 4 lines then i get this

Comment: When i run Grunt in the bash terminal -> Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue. Then i do a grunt --force and then it comes with: Done, but with warnings.